# Why are PHP variables not working with blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, blueimp

I have recently started using the blueimp jquery file upload however I have stumbled across a problem.

I want to assign a php variable to the path that the image should be uploaded into.

This is the code

```
 $haha = $_COOKIE['nameofcookie'];

 function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true) {
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
        'upload_dir' => '../../../mem/$haha/',
        'upload_url' => 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/$haha/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
        'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
```

$haha is the PHP variable that I have assigned to the cookie I have placed on the user.

However when I execute the code it makes a directory called $haha - not the id of the user.

I have tried to use "$haha" or ' . $haha . ' but none of this works.

Can anyone help? If you can it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter that I have named the main file index.php instead of index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single ones (and [read some documentation on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php))

`"http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/$haha/",`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options...

My favorite [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) use %d for integer or %s for string:

```
'upload_dir' => sprintf("../../../mem/%d/", $haha),
'upload_url' => sprintf("http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/%d/", $haha),
```

or using double-quotes:

```
'upload_dir' => "../../../mem/{$haha}/",
'upload_url' => "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/{$haha}/",
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it displays the error: Error SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Comment: @hakimierfan Not sure how the JSON error relates? `var_dump($this->options)` as see if the $haha is replaced with your ID properly. If $haha is defined, then it should be.

Comment: $haha is not defined. See my answer.

Comment: I tried putting it in the class and I still  get the same error

Comment: Why are you using __construct() if it wasn't already in a class?

Comment: I dont know, it was just there when I downloaded the files, what should I change it too?

Comment: Does it matter that I have named the main file index.php instead of index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
'upload_dir' => '../../../mem/'.$haha.'/',
'upload_url' => 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/'.$haha.'/',
```

hope it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "$this->" since it's in a class. Then you either have to use double quotes or the concatenate operator (which look like a period):

```
'upload_dir' => '../../../mem/'.$this->haha.'/',
'upload_url' => 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/'.$this->haha.'/',
```

And within your class, $haha has to be defined with "var":

```
var $haha = $_COOKIE['nameofcookie'];
```

Comment: thanks but I somehow get the error: Error SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Comment: how come that happens, is there some option i should change?

Comment: Your original question has already been answered. Now you're asking questions about things that have nothing to do with it. Try to narrow down the problem with some basic troubleshooting, and if you can't figure it out, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/"'.$haha.'"/',
```

instead of:

```
'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mem/$haha/',
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the error: Error SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Answer (score 0):

look at the constructor, it allows you to pass $options which must be an array. $options will be merged with $this->options.

```
  if ($options) {
        $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);
    }
```

the above statement shows how it does.

Now i explain how to pass path to the constructor:
1. first declare an object for the class:

```
 $options=array('upload_url'=>'your/path','upload_dir'=>'your/path');
 $uploadHandler=  new UploadHandler($options);
```

What this does is that it will set the upload_url and upload_path as you need.

Note: if the keys in the $options match with that defined inside the constructor function, the values will override the values stored for that key in the constructor and when key does not match, the keys value pair will be added.

$haha = $_COOKIE['nameofcookie'];
This variable seems to be class variable. You also need to a firm grip of OOP concept. When accessing class variable inside class method, you should use $this->haha.